# Agregate Functions MAX and AVG are not working with DATEDIFF in Hibernate HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am using Hibernate3, trying to execute following HQL query, it is giving below errors.

Query: `select MAX(DATEDIFF(SECOND, startTime, endTime)) from Service_Master`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.AggregateNode 
+-[AGGREGATE] AggregateNode: 'MAX'
|  \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
|     +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'DATEDIFF' {originalText=DATEDIFF}
|     \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
|        +-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'SECOND' {originalText=SECOND}
```

Query: `select AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, startTime, endTime)) from Service_Master`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$AvgFunction.determineJdbcTypeCode(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:98)
at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$AvgFunction.render(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:92)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator.endFunctionTemplate(SqlGenerator.java:214)
```

I tried lot of ways to solve this issue, used custom dialect and added function definition to DATEDIFF and MAX functions using SQLFunction in constructor, used SQL CAST function, etc.., still it is not working...
It is urgent requirement, please can any one answer this or re-direct me to a link where i can get solution for this.

Comment: whats database you use? which version?

Comment: You may find something helpful at https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2436442

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: I sub-classed the SQLServerDialect, and from the constructor call, i added the following things, but still it didn't work. registerFunction("datediff", new StandardSQLFunction("datediff", Hibernate.INTEGER));

Comment: No answer found for this, using native SQL execution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would have been helpfull:

When I was trying to select a max value for an integer, i got the same error. For whatever reason, I had to CAST my value explicitely to an integer.

```
<class name="WhateverXY" table="Whatever" lazy="false" mutable="false">
     <id name="id" column="id" type="integer" >
         <generator class="native">
             <param name="sequence">ATTACHMENT_ID_SEQUENCE</param>
         </generator>
    </id>
    <version name="version" column="version" unsaved-value="negative"/>
    <property name="paramString" column="param1" type="string" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="paramInt" column="param2" type="integer" not-null="true"/>
    [...]
    <query name="WhateverXY.myQuery">from WhateverXYwhere (paramString, paramInt) in (select paramString, max(CAST(paramInt as integer)) from WhateverXY group by paramString)</query>
</class>
```

I didn't do any further analysis, due to strict time boxes, but maybe someone else can explain this.